# Show some help text over a UITableView if the UITableView happens to be blank

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've got an app with several UITableViews in it, and if one of them is empty, I'd like to display a bit of help text, floating in front of the UITableView:

"Looks like you haven't created anything for this list yet. Make your first entry by tapping the button above."

How do I present this view, floating in front of the UITableView?

1. What method of the UITableViewDelegate would be used to present this view?
2. What would the code look like to present the view?
3. What method of the UITableViewDelegate would be used to hide this view once the user adds content?

Here's a quick mockup:

[image: Mockup]

Comment: You could use [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare in .h file

UIView *root;

in .m file

import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

    root = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 50, 220, 250)];
    root.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    root.layer.cornerRadius=10;
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 50)];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.numberOfLines=3;
    label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
    label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text=@"Make your first entry by tapping the button at the top of the screen";
    [root addSubview:label];
    [self.view addSubview:root];
}
```

inside your button Event method

[root removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 1):

in viewDidLoad/Appear,
create a view and add it as subview `[self.view addSubview:infoView]` . on click event of + button remove it from superview `[infoView removeFromSuperView]`

Answer (score 0):

I would create/remove the view in numberOfRowsInSection (if it is 0 then show the view) or whatever it is called. As for the view itself, have a UILabel in a custom view. To add the rounded corners etc you can access the view's layer, which is a CALayer. Oh and make sure that you have an ivar for the view so you can remove it easily and check if it is visible. And make sure you always reload the table view when you show your view, as otherwise numberOfRowsInSection will not be called.